# Ruby Why does the foo.methods not work in yield.methods or yield.class

Tags: ruby, yield

I tried to use .methods to list the methods for yield in Ruby. But it doesn't work, does yield have no methods

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `yield` is not an object, it is a keyword, and hence, it have no methods.

[Here](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/18-blocks/lessons/54-yield) is a good (and short) tutorial about `yield` in ruby

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?